# Transforming array into a object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to convert an array into a javscript object that is designed to work with input checkboxes in AngularJS.

This is the input array that I get from my backend:

```
let selectedRolesDB = ['ADMIN', 'SECURITY'];
```

This is what my front-end expects:

```
let selectedRoles =
  {
    'ADMIN' : true,
    'SECURITY': true
  };
```

I tried different approaches such as angular.forEach but the problem is that I am not able to get the desired output:

```
angular.forEach(selectedRolesDB,(value, key) => {
    this.selectedRoles.push({value : true });
});
```

Can anyone tell me how I best solve my problem so I end up with the array that my front-end expects?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doonot/wh7xeo5y/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectedRoles` is not array, it is object. Init it as empty object:

```
let selectedRoles = {};

angular.forEach(selectedRolesDB,(value, key) => {
    // use [] notation to add property with required name and value
    selectedRoles[value] = true;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `array.reduce` :

```js
    let selectedRolesDB = ['ADMIN', 'SECURITY'];
    const newArray = selectedRolesDB.reduce((accumulator, value) => {
       accumulator[value] = true;
       return accumulator;
    }, {});
    
    console.log(newArray)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce for  documentation about it.

Comment: The question is marked with typescript, for typescript, you should also declare the type of the accumulator as depending on compiler flags you will get an error otherwise: `const newArray = selectedRolesDB.reduce<{ [role: string]: boolean }>((accumulator, value) => {
   accumulator[value] = true;
   return accumulator;
}, {});`

Comment: Indeed, @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, however (according to the code provided in the question), the ts compiler does not use  any specific flag and seems very permissive (also we cannot write a snippet in typescript :( )

Answer (score 0):

Probably it would be much better to use array's native 'forEach' method (it has a good browser support, see here [Array forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)). Also this will be helpful if you decide to migrate your project into Angular2+, so avoiding usages of 'angular.someMethod' is a better approach.
This is a final solution:

```
const selectedRoles: {[key: string]: boolean} = {};
selectedRolesDB.forEach((value: string) => selectedRoles[value] = true);
```